# Laravel Eloquent ORM whereHas and where in foreach

Tags: php

I am trying to make the following work, it might be bad practice, I am pretty new to Laravel, so please let me know !

I have a model named `Files`, those are linked to the `Keywords` through a pivot table.

I am running the following code, but I get `Undefined variable: keyword_id` as error.

```
$keyword_ids = array(148, 4);
$files    = new Files;

foreach($keyword_ids as $keyword_id)
{
    $files = $files->whereHas('keywords', function($query)
    {
        $query->where('id', '=', $keyword_id);
    });
}
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Could you share your Files Model and the database? That might help for figuring this one. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the `use` keyword to have your variables accessible inside the closure.

```
foreach($keyword_ids as $keyword_id)
{
    $files = $files->whereHas('keywords', function($query) use ($keyword_id)
    {
        $query->where('id', '=', $keyword_id);
    });
}
```

Comment: Awesome man, never used `use` before :) Thanks for your very quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can go without **foreach** and use **whereIn** to check if **id** matches any of **$keyword_ids** values.

```
$files = $files->whereHas('keywords', function($query) use ($keyword_ids)
    {
        $query->whereIn('id', $keyword_ids);
    });
```